# Refresh an iframe without refreshing the entire page

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, refresh, reload

I have an iframe that I would like to automatically refresh itself without doing a whole page refresh.  I would prefer to use javascript or jquery.  This is what I have been trying unsuccessfully.

```
<div class="Widget"><!--DARK SKY-->
    <div class="WidgetHeader">
        <img src = "images/WidgetHeaders/DarkSky.png"></div>
    <div id="DarkSky" style="width: auto; height: 245px; padding: 5px; background-color: hsla(0,0%,100%,.9);">
        <iframe id="forecast_embed" type="text/html" frameborder="0" height="245" width="100%" src="http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=38.269571&lon=-85.487420&name=Louisville&units=us&color=#4c7cba"> </iframe>
    </div>   
</div>

<script type = "text/javascript">
    window.onload = function() {   
        setInterval(function refreshDarkSky() {  
            document.getElementById("#forecast_embed").src ="http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=38.269571&lon=-85.487420&name=Louisville&units=us&color=#4c7cba"
        }, 90000);
    } 
</script>
```

Answer (score 5):

if iframe is not from different domain, you can use:

```
document.getElementById('forecast_embed').contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

for cross domain,

```
var iframe = document.getElementById('forecast_embed');
iframe.src = iframe.src;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            setInterval(function refreshDarkSky() {
                $("#forecast_embed").attr("src","http://forecast.io/embed/#lat=38.269571&lon=-85.487420&name=Louisville&units=us&color=#4c7cba"); 
            }, 90000);
        });
```

Comment: Can you provide your html?

Comment: just added it, sorry for not getting that on there from the start

Comment: It will take almost 9 minutes to reload thw content. Change 90000 with 9000 for testing purpose

Comment: yes, but it displays weather information.  Weather info doesn't change that quickly.  I always give it plenty of time to refresh when testing.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
$('#forecast_embed',window.parent.document).attr('src',
             $('#forecast_embed',window.parent.document).attr('src'));
```

It has to untie your issue.

Answer (score -1):

try this

```
window.top.location.reload();
```